# Adding eclipse plugin to marketplace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I have developed a eclipse plugin for my platform. Is there any way to add my eclipse plugin into market place so that whom ever needs to connect my platform can download that plugin from a common place(market place).
Or is there any other way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a link ***[Add Content](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/addcontent)*** on the [Eclipse Marketplace website](http://marketplace.eclipse.org) that describes exactly what needs to be done.

Technically, the **Marketplace does not host the plugin but only refers to an external update site**. So before you can create a Marketplace entry, you need a public server for your update site / p2 repository that contains the plugin.